# Typescript require not working

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have 3 typescript files: main.ts, print.ts, log.ts

I installed node modules and used typescript compiler - tsc main.ts - to compile .ts files.
After that, I tried to run index.html with `npm start`, but console.log says require is not defined.  Am I still missing something? I use Visual Studio Code editor.

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>this is the title</title>

<style type="text/css">

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
</div>

<script type='text/javascript' src='main.js'></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**MAIN.TS**

```
import log = require('./log')
import print = require('./print')
log.logMessage();
print.printMessage();
```

**PRINT.TS**

```
export function printMessage() {
   console.log('print');
}
```

**LOG.TS**

```
export function logMessage() {
   console.log('log');
}
```

Console.log should say 'log' and 'print', but it doesn't.

Comment: when you export the function you can call it directly. try in your main.ts: log(); and print();

Comment: I think you want either `const log = require('./log');` or `import log from './log';`. I'd be surprised if this wasn't throwing an error somewhere.

Comment: yes in typescript you do: import { logMessage} from "./log"; without require

Comment: Someone has to define what 'require' is in browser. And its not nessesary to bundle your app for this purpose. You can use systemjs (http://david-barreto.com/how-to-use-typescript-with-systemjs/) or if you want to make your life a bit easier - jspm (http://jspm.io/) that is based on systemjs.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. The important part of your question is

> but console.log says **require is not defined**

`require` is used in node's module system, called CommonJS. Browsers do not understand this system by default. You have to use a bundler, like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [fuse-box](http://fuse-box.org/)

TypeScript can not really bundle your application :-/